# Sculptmode paint with image texture has no color and is black and white

Tags: vertex-paint, sculpt-mode

Using an image texture under brush settings in sculpt mode makes the texture loose its color information.
[image]

Using the same settings in vertex paint mode works as expected (ignore the yellow tint):
[image]

(I want to use the new 'roll' mapping mode for textures in sculptmode, otherwise I'd just use vertex color mode)